# how to install ast python package

Tags: software-installation, python

I'm using django constance in my project. This app used a python package ast. When I try to install that package using command `pip-2.7 install ast`, it results as "`Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement ast`".

Can some one help me how to install this package in CentOS? I tried searching in google, unfortunately I couldn't find any link.

Answer (score 3):

[ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) is part of the standard library of python, you don't need to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to install packages through the <random program> package handler, do it through your distribution's package handler.If not, both will end up with partial or conflicting views of what is there.